# How to fetch the number of active lambda workers using ruby aws sdk?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

So, using AWS Lambda with ruby sdk I can this to call a function:

```
Aws::Lambda::Client.new.invoke_async params
```

is there any way to query for the number of currently running lambda instances?

```
Aws::Lambda::Client.new.number_of_running_instances # returns 17
```

Comment: I don't think there is, but you can track metrics associated with Lambda invocations using CloudWatch Metrics. Why do you want to know the number of concurrent Lambda functions?

Comment: I have peaks of Lambda calls triggered from Rails, but because these calls consume too much of the database, I have to limit the number of active lambda instances running at a given time. I'd like to write a daemon that would, from time to time (say 5min) ensure we are using all the lambda calls we can/need.

Like: Spaws 30 workers, from 30 workers, 13 are finished 5 minutes later, so I want to spin up 13 new workers.

Comment: Not sure how decoupled your clients are from the Lambdas, but could you use SQS and do some kind of request batching?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [CloudWatch Metrics API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/v3/api/Aws/CloudWatch/Metric.html) to list [AWS Lambda Metrics](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/monitoring-functions-metrics.html), including number of concurrent executions (namespace: `AWS/Lambda`, metric: `ConcurrentExecutions`), however there is a caveat. As stated in the documentation of the `ConcurrentExecutions` metric:

> Emitted as an aggregate metric for all functions in the account, and for functions that have a custom concurrency limit specified. [...] Measures the sum of concurrent executions for a given function at a given point in time. Must be viewed as an average metric if aggregated across a time period.

Consequently, you must [Manage Concurrency](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/concurrent-executions.html#per-function-concurrency) by setting a concurrency limit on your Lambda function before you can view the concurrent execution for a specific function. On the other hand, based on the comments to the question, this may solve the problem you are facing with the choked database. As a side effect, you may have to deal with throttled Lambda invocations instead.